# call code behind function from JS using DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax

Would like to call a code behind method from my JS page. have looked at few examples on the site but cant seem to get it working. Tried function () { ReloadUploadedImages_click();, also AJAX.

On my JS page I am using DOM elements to create a button and display it on screen inside the 'DivHolding2Tabs'

```
    var button = document.createElement("input");
    button.type = "button";
    button.id = "myBtn";
    button.value = "im a button";
    DivHolding2Tabs.appendChild(button);
```

When the button is clicked I want to call the `ReloadUploadedImages_click();` on the MapUserControl.ascx.cs

So far iv tried:

```
button.onclick = function () { ReloadUploadedImages_click(); };
```

&

```
//button.addEventListener("click", myFunction);

function myFunction() {
alert("BEFORE");
//ReloadUploadedImages_click();
// PageMethods.ReloadUploadedImages_click();

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'MapUserControl.ascx/ReloadUploadedImages_click',
    data: "",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (msg) {
        alert("SUCCESS");
    },
    error: function (e) {
        alert("fail");
    }
});


alert("AFTER");
```

}

Can't get it working. Anyone have any idea as to what is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

you could try:

```
$('#DivHolding2Tabs').on('click', 'button#myBtn', function() {
    ReloadUploadedImages_click();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
button.setAttribute("onclick", function() { alert("alert"); });
```

Answer (score 0):

I am answering based on an assumption that
DivHolding2Tabs is defined correctly because it might be the problem but I wouldn't know

Perhaps a css code is messing up where the DOM is located something invisible might be on top of your button..

Check Inspect Element in Chrome if you haven't you might find your error there..